# Why my Http request is done with `GET` instead of `POST`?

Tags: java, android

Why the code below do some `GET` request instead of `POST` resquest. I receive also CONTENT_TYPE: "" :(

```
HashMap<String, String> PostDataMap = new HashMap<>();
  PostDataMap.put("method","any");
  String PostDataString = HTTPEncodeParamNameValues(PostDataMap);

  URL url = new URL(ApiServerURL);
  HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();     
  httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
  httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
  httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
  httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
  httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);

  DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream()); 
  dataOutputStream.writeBytes(PostDataString);
  dataOutputStream.flush();
  dataOutputStream.close();

  InputStream inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int length;
  while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
  }
```

Comment: Who is teling you about a get request?

Comment: I catch the request on the server. it's GET and even Content-Type is "" and content length is 0. I don't understand what i do wrong

Comment: Is there a proxy involved?

Comment: @greenapps no their is no proxy

Comment: @greenapps : seam that adding httpURLConnection.getResponseCode(); make the post working, but i can't understand why !

Comment: Very strange deed.

Comment: yea can't understand :(

Answer (score 0):

when you pass some **user input** to server that time used **post** and only getting data **no user input** that time used **get**.

when used **get** that time all data call in **url**. and it **limited size**. and also **not secure**.
when you used **post** that not go data into url. and is **unlimited data** to be send .and **also secure**.